# python windows: exit a loop when cmd window closes

Tags: python, cmd

I run the following code in a cmd window. Many different exceptions may occur within the try loop, this is why I generalize to except all exceptions. But: If I close the cmd window the code runs in, how do I stop the code from keep running even though the cmd window is closed.

```
while True:
   try: 
       print('test') # in actual code more complicateed task with many possible exceptions
   except Exception:
      pass
```

Right now, I can only quit this code via a restart.

EDIT: I tried to catch the exception but the log file only says "log works"

```
import sys
from time import sleep
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename="logtest.log",
                        filemode='a',
                        format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s % 
(levelname)s %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                        level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.info("log works")
while True:
    try:
        print('test')
        sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info(e)
        logging.info(str(e))
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to determine the type of exception raised when the command window is closed (for example, by using the `except` block to log information to a file, or by reading the documentation for the standard exception hierarchy)?

Comment: Also what command are you using to execute your script?

Comment: windows command line interface

Comment: How did you determine that the script continues running after the cmd window is closed?  Windows should not let that happen unless you are explicitly doing something to detach a subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in your try statement you need to set a condition where the execution breaks for example below:

```
    x = 0
    while True:
        try:
            if (x == 10):
                break
            else:
                   # in actual code more complicated task with many possible exceptions
                   print('test')
                   x += 1
            
        except Exception as e:
            print(e.printStackTrace())
```

Another method can be using a keyword to force break out of the while loop for example below we are using q to end the loop execution:

'''
from time import sleep
import re

input_text= ""
while True:
try:
# in actual code more complicateed task with many possible exceptions
input_text = input("Enter your selection .....")
print(input_text)
if re.search('q' , input_text , re.IGNORECASE):
break

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e.printStackTrace())
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Well, your script never received any exception, it was just killed without any possibility to log anything.

We are not in the Unix world where a shell just kindly telss its child that it is exiting with a SIGHUP signal letting them know where they want to die or not. We are in a MS/DOS inheritance: when a console ends, every process attached to the console dies.

So unless you have detached the process from its console it is over. You can easily control it with Windows task manager (start it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd>)